# Change Shopify-Logo of Admin-LogIn-Box

Tags: shopify

Does anybody know **how to change the default-shopify-logo**, which appears at the top of the log-in-box before getting to the admin-area?

Cheers,
Tobi

[image: shopify log-in-box]

Comment: What did you tried? I never used shopify and am a noob in html/php, but I ll search for where does the image come from, and either change the link or change the image itself.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt Shopify will let you alter their branding of their App.

Comment: just to add to this, this dialog is part of the shopify admin area so you won't be able to change anything in this or the authorization dialog that comes after it.